# How do I get the relative path of a file in a project?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to create a build system for my app where it will open a url to the target file.  For example, if I run the build on a project file `components/flower.html`, it should run

`open http://localhost:8080/app/components/flower.html`

The list of variables for ST don't have relative path. so the closest I get is

`http://localhost:8080/app//dev/myproject/components/flower.html`

It contains the full path.  Perhaps there is an easy way to remove the `/dev/myproject` part?

This is the build setting I want to further customise:

`"cmd": ["open", "http://localhost:8080/app/${file_path}"]`

Answer (score 0):

[If we look at the documentation on Build Systems, we see that we can use snippet substitution in the variables used in the build system.](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#placeholders-for-variables) This is really handy when the built in variables don't quite meet our needs.

Therefore, we can replace the project dir with nothing to get a relative path.

I find the easiest way to test substitutions is using a snippet for `$SELECTION`, so you can just change the selected text and try a different test case, without needing to worry about saving the file with different names or running the build system and waiting for the results.

The substitution is done with regular expressions, where forward slashes need to be escaped, as they have special meaning. One slash after the variable name, one slash after the find regex pattern, one slash after that, followed by the replacement pattern, followed by a slash to indicate the end of the replacement pattern and optionally followed by some regex flags. Therefore, the snippet I'm using is:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
${SELECTION/^\/dev\/myproject\///}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

This just matches from the beginning of the string (`^`), then the literal `/dev/myproject/` (unfortunately variables can't be used in regex patterns, otherwise we could maybe use `$project_path`) and replaces it with nothing. As we are only expecting one match, we don't need to use the `g`lobal regex modifier flag.

The output we get from that with a selection of `/dev/myproject/components/flower.html` is:

> ```
> components/flower.html
> ```

Which seems to be what we want, because with `http://localhost:8080/app/` preceding it, it becomes `http://localhost:8080/app/components/flower.html`.

So, now we can just take the variable part out the snippet, and replace `SELECTION` with `file_path`, so it will operate on the current file's path instead of the selection, just like you had originally, and plug that into your build system:

```
"cmd": ["open", "http://localhost:8080/app/${file_path/^\/dev\/myproject\///}"]
```

Comment: Replacement did not to work.  Thank you for your answer, it would be better than my temp solution of having a separate `build.sh` file, but I haven't figured out how to make it work yet, i'll try again later.